# How do I change an Angular UI Bootstrap panel color when the panel is open

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to change the panel color of the parent that is open.  I was told I could use something called "panel-class" but my attempts to use if have been unsuccessful.  I copied the sample code directly from the "example" that was provided but still the panel color does not change.  I am trying to use this in an MVC _Layout.cshtml page.  Could that be the reason?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app/AccordionCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app/generalsearchService.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <nav>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div>

    </div>
    <div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="AccordionCtrl">

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="group-template.html">
            <div class="panel {{panelClass || 'panel-default'}}">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#fa39c3">
                        <a href tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-transclude="heading">
                            <span ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">{{heading}}</span>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" collapse="!isOpen">
                    <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: right" ng-transclude></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>

        <p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.open = !status.open">Toggle last panel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.isFirstDisabled = ! status.isFirstDisabled">Enable / Disable first panel</button>
        </p>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
                Open only one at a time
            </label>
        </div>
        <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
            <accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
                This content is straight in the template.
            </accordion-group>
            <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
                {{group.content}}
            </accordion-group>
            <accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
                <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
                <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
            </accordion-group>
            <accordion-group heading="Custom template" template-url="group-template.html">
                Hello
            </accordion-group>
            <accordion-group heading="Delete account" panel-class="panel-danger">
                <p>Please, to delete your account, click the button below</p>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </accordion-group>
            <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
                <accordion-heading>
                    I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
                </accordion-heading>
                This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
    </div>
    <div id="myBody" style="margin-top:50px; margin-left:320px; width:80%; position:absolute">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)



</body>
</html>
```

Here is what it looks like when I run it:

[image: Accordion Panel-Class Example]

As you can see, the text color changes on the one example, but the panel color does not change on the "Delete" tab. Thanks in advance for any assistance. Have a great day all!

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for you, check out my github page:
https://github.com/brendancopley/customDirectives/tree/master/custom-accordion-ui-bootstrap

Here's the example DEMO https://brendancopley.github.io/customDirectives/custom-accordion-ui-bootstrap/

I made a Custom Directive of UI-Bootstrap Accordion.

To answer your question, it's really simple:

> .panel.panel-open {
>      color: orangered 
>      }

Or you can add an id to your uib-accordion-group and then include it in the css to have different color when opened for each heading you want.

> ```
> <div uib-accordion-group id="anything" class="panel-white" is-open='menuStatus[2].isOpen'>
>   <uib-accordion-heading>
>     <i style="padding-right:10px;" class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': menuStatus[2].isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-up': !menuStatus[2].isOpen}"></i>Example Heading
>   </uib-accordion-heading>
>   <p>blah blah blah blah</p>
> </div>
> ```

And then in your CSS add this

> #anything.panel.panel-open {
>     color: #8f42f4; }

Answer (score -2):

Per the examples [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion), you can see that the `Delete account` accordion uses the `panel-class` attribute to change/override the default class and the `I can have markup, too!` accordion shows how to use `ng-class` to set a class based on whether or not the accordion is open.

Either open the Plunker from this example or fork it and change the `panel-class` attribute from `panel-danger` to `panel-success` to see the change.  Additionally, you can change the `glyphicon-chevron-down` and `glyphicon-chevron-right` classes to your own custom classes and they will get applied on open or close.

In the future, please read the documentation and examples thoroughly before asking for help.  Per SO's own guidelines, show that you've attempted to solve the issue before asking for help.

Comment: I did read the documentation and tried to use the example as it was written, but the panel color did not change, so I asked for help.  You have no idea how much time and research I've spent trying to figure this out, which I still have not, so to make the statement that I should attempt to solve the issue before asking for help when you have no idea how much effort I have put into it thus far is insulting.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff, and you need to understand that people open nearly a dozen issues each day in the UI Bootstrap forum and most of them are due to the developer not spending enough time researching the issue.  You are a developer.  One of the core tenets of your job is to debug why something isn't working.  Lambasting a developer for helping is not going to get you what you want.

Comment: As I said, you have no idea what time I have spent, so automatically assuming that I haven't spent any is ridiculous.  I am new to Angular so "debugging" what I don't understand is difficult.  You went from bashing me for asking for help to telling me my job.  If you don't want to help, then don't, but there is no need for you to attack me.  Jeez!

Comment: Whatever, dude.  We pointed you to exact, working examples multiple times.